# I want to combine two tables by selecting the id entered by the user in Laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel, laravel-5, join

I want to retrieve the full name column in the user_detail table, by the user entering the selected id first in the Order table using Query Builder

in the order table it looks like this

```
 +"id": 1
  +"order_detail_id": 115
  +"user_id": 3
  +"status": "pending"
  +"updated_at": "2019-11-22 17:53:56"
  +"created_at": "2019-11-22 15:44:28"
```

in table user_detail it looks like this

```
 +"id": 3
  +"full_name": michael jackson
  +"address": "bla bla bla"
  +"updated_at": "2019-11-22 17:53:56"
  +"created_at": "2019-11-22 15:44:28"
```

I want if the user enters id 1 it will output like

```
            "id": 1,
            "order_detail_id": 115,
            "user_id": 3,
            "full_name": "michael jackson",
            "address" : "bla bla bla" 
            "status": "pending"
```

I tried with this code but an error still appears

```
 $cekclient = DB::table('order')
                                ->where('id',$request->id)
                                ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'order.user_id')
                                ->select('order.*','user.name','user.address',)
                                ->get();

            dd($cekclient);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. please give table alias and use them in select and join.

```
$cekclient  = DB::table('order as or')
            ->select('or*','u.name','u.address') // here you can add column names which you need in output
            ->leftJoin('user as u', 'u.id', '=', 'or.user_id')
            ->where('or.id',$request->id) // here if you need data by id of user then use u.id in where insead of or.id
            ->get();
```

Comment: does the Query Builder have to be a relation in the Model? Because I get an error like this, even though in the database I have related it ? Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation

Comment: Query Builder is different to eloquent.  Query Builder not use Model.